# Generating TypeScript from WSDL or WADL

Tags: rest, typescript, soap

How can I convert WSDL or WADL to typescript code?
and if I can't, how can I handle large dto from the server that changed its signature?
I there a way to know it has been changed?

thanks

Comment: I've thought about this before (and have thought about working on something to do this). I don't think there's anything out there to do it, but it would be very useful to be able to have a compile time error when a web service changes. Using another library in combination with [TypeLITE](http://type.litesolutions.net/) would seem good to me.

Comment: I'm in need of something similar myself. I'm assuming it conventional to have both a application.wadl + schema. Then you'd have to generate Typescript interfaces by combining data from both.

Answer (score 2):

[Rest Client Generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rest-client-generator) seems to able to convert WADL files into Typescript code to be used together with the Angular2 or Dojo2 framework.

Comment: Yes.. Found and tried that today.. Getting Error: self signed certificate ... code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'...

Comment: I worked around 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'. and posted here if anyone else gets same issue: https://github.com/dzurikmiroslav/rest-client-generator/issues/5

Answer (score 2):

You could try [wsdl-to-ts](https://github.com/TimLuq/wsdl-to-ts)

> A CLI tool and library for nodejs to generate TypeScript typings from a WSDL service.

Comment: This tool makes wrong results, here is what is wrong https://gist.github.com/gitowiec/4e279a83a0fe404e46f5937474fbfc88

Answer (score 1):

> How can I convert WSDL or WADL to typescript code

I do not know of an open source project that does *this*. However you can either start one *or* step back (at a level above *WSDL*) and do a codegen directly based on your C# / F# (.NET) data structures using something like TypeLITE.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like https://github.com/dderevjanik/wsdl-tsclient is a common option these days. Haven’t tried it yet though.